# Ubuntu 18.04 freeze after each reboot

Tags: 18.04, freeze

I´m running Ubuntu 18.04. Since last week I´ve been struggling with rapid freezing - it appears after approximatelly 5 minutes. The only way is to reboot the system. I haven´t performed any update.

The details of Ubuntu.
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic

When typing "uname -r" the result is: 4.4.0-18362-Microsof.
linux-generic-hwe-18.04 is already the newest version (5.3.0.42.99).
xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04 is already the newest version (1:7.7+19ubuntu8~18.04.3).

I´ve tried many corrections I googled but still without any success. I´m new to Ubuntu. Please, could you help me? Where is the problem?

Thanks a lot
Regards
Adam

Comment: I've been having an extremely similar issue! What type of computer are you using?

Comment: I´m using Windows 10 pro 64 bit, processor: Intel r Core tm i5-5300 cpu. I was working with Ubuntu 18.04 for last few months without any struggle but since last week (don´t know wheter some update has been released) it´s always freezing. I can´t even try to run some fixxing methods since it freezes in the middle of the code. Do you still face the same issue? Or have you already fixed it? If so, please, share with me.

Comment: I just managed to fix it by going into the BIOS and turning off C-states. That might work for you?

Comment: Well, my motherboard doesn´t support UEFI so I can´t access UEFI firmware settings, thus I cannot turn off C-states I guess. Do you know if there´s another possibility how to turn off C-states?

Comment: I´ve found out the problem is related to WSL since they released the update of the WSL Linux kernel (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/win...sl/wsl2-kernel). After this update (I didn´t know about it) the freezing problems occur. Please, if you had any advice how to address this issue I would be very grateful for it.

Comment: I don't have any advice, then. Sorry! I know it's a catastrophic bug.